# Azure Log Analytics purge requests failing with Internal Server Error

Tags: azure, powershell, rest, azure-log-analytics

I am trying to `purge` few records from an Azure Log Analytics workspace table.

I am following the documentation from https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/loganalytics/workspace-purge/purge

My account has `Data Purger` RBAC role added. Also, I am an `Owner` on the subscription.

1. I have tried the `Try it` button on the  documentation page, but get `Internal Server` error after triggering the HTTP post request.

Request Body/Payload

```json
{
    filters: [
    {
        "column": "TimeGenerated",
        "operator": ">",
        "value": "2022-05-26T06:09:00"
    }],
    table: "AppRequests"
}
```

error response

```json
{
  "error": {
    "code": "InternalServerError",
    "message": "Operation Id: 1df0f52bd248b548b713baf53288eec6"
  }
}
```

2. I have also coded a PowerShell script and tried but getting the same error my script:

```
param(
    [Parameter(Mandatory = $true)][string]$SubscriptionName,
    [Parameter(Mandatory = $true)][string]$ResourceGroupName,
    [Parameter(Mandatory = $true)][string]$WorkspaceName

)
Set-AzContext -Subscription $SubscriptionName | Out-Null
$AzContext = Get-AzContext 
$AzAccessToken = Get-AzAccessToken -TenantId $AzContext.Tenant.Id
$Token = $AzAccessToken.Token

$SubscriptionId = $AzContext.Subscription.Id

$LogAnalyticsPurgeUriBase = "https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/$SubscriptionId/resourceGroups/$ResourceGroupName/providers/Microsoft.OperationalInsights/workspaces/$WorkspaceName/purge?api-version=2020-08-01";

Write-Host $LogAnalyticsPurgeUriBase

$AuthHeader = @{
    'Content-Type'  = 'application/json'
    'Authorization' = "Bearer $Token"
}

Write-Host $AuthHeader

$Body = @"
{
    "table": "AppRequests",
    "filters": [
    {
        "column": "TimeGenerated",
        "operator": ">",
        "value": "2022-05-26T06:09:00"
    }]
}
"@
Write-Host $Body 
$PurgeResult = Invoke-RestMethod -Method Post -Uri $LogAnalyticsPurgeUriBase -Body $Body -Headers $AuthHeader
Return $PurgeResult;
```

error response after executing the PowerShell script ( and passing the parameters )

```json
 {"error":{"code":"InternalServerError","message":"Operation Id: 4159055a9a69bb44afd3509c3a2d42ca"}}
```

I have gone to the Log Analytics activity log - events pane and tried getting more details on the error there, but unfortunately the events details there also just mention 'Internal Server' error without expanding any details.

Any guidance on what I am doing wrong would be much appreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Issue is unrelated to anything you performed (No client-side error is visible in the response). it originates from the RP (Azure Resource provider), 500 is a server-side error, hence - they will need to address it. if you have the option to open a ticket with their support that will be recommended as next move.

Comment: Alright, I will raise a support ticket with them. Thank you!